# FS module doesn't work after packaging in electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm trying to learn electron by creating a simple project and it works when I write start it with `npm start`, but when I package it with the electron packager, the node js part doesn't work anymore.

This is the main process :

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain , globalShortcut} = require('electron');
const fs = require('fs');

let mainWindow;

function createWindow () {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1200,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: false
    }
  });
  mainWindow.loadFile('src/index.html');

  globalShortcut.register('f5', function() {
        mainWindow.reload()
    })
};

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow()

app.on('activate', () => {
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
      createWindow()
    }
  })
});

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
});

ipcMain.on("message", (event, arg) => {
    const data = {
      "num": arg
    };
    fs.writeFile('src/data.json', JSON.stringify(data), () => {
      event.returnValue = "success";
    })
})
```

and this is the renderer process:

```
const {ipcRenderer} = require("electron");
const saveBtn = document.getElementById('saveBtn');
const inp = document.getElementById('inp');
const fetchBtn = document.getElementById('fetchBtn');

saveBtn.onclick = () => {
  if (!inp.value) return alert("Your input is empty");
  if (isNaN(inp.value)) return alert("The input is not a number");

  ipcRenderer.sendSync("message", inp.value);
}

fetchBtn.onclick = () => {
  fetch("data.json")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => console.log(res.num))
}
```

This is the package.json file: (ignore the electron-forge things)

```
{
  "name": "electron-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "build": {
    "asar": false
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron-forge start",
    "package": "electron-forge package",
    "make": "electron-forge make"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@electron-forge/cli": "^6.0.0-beta.54",
    "@electron-forge/maker-deb": "^6.0.0-beta.54",
    "@electron-forge/maker-rpm": "^6.0.0-beta.54",
    "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel": "^6.0.0-beta.54",
    "@electron-forge/maker-zip": "^6.0.0-beta.54",
    "electron": "^12.0.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "config": {
    "forge": {
      "packagerConfig": {},
      "makers": [
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel",
          "config": {
            "name": "electron_project"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-zip",
          "platforms": [
            "darwin"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-deb",
          "config": {}
        },
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-rpm",
          "config": {}
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

and the data.json file is just an  object with a `num` property and a value.

When I run the program with `npm start` I can give a value and change the value of the json file, but when I packaged the app with electron packager, it wasn't working.

Also sorry for the messy code I wrote. I've just started learning to code.

Comment: It does not look like you have specified `fs` as a dependency so it is not being bundled in the app

Comment: What exactly does "it doesn't work" mean? Are you getting any errors, any output? Does the `BrowserWindow` load the HTML file you specified or does the app simply not launch? I can confirm that what @spring suggested is not necessary. However, you have to be careful with the paths -- they might be different after packaging.

Comment: Alexander was right. Once I built the app using electron-builder, the path to the json file changed so I had to get the new path and then it worked. Before, I even changed the code so that it will give an error if it couldn’t write the file and then will display the message to the ipcRenderer, but it didn’t give any error so I changed the code again to read the file instead of writing it and then it finally gave and error that said the path is not correct. Thanks a lot to anyone who commented. This was my first time using stack overflow and I’m just blown away by this amazing community.